# Elixir/Phoenix query return empty if condition fails

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to return the value by joining on another table in query, but is it possible to still include the element in the final results, if non value was found from secondary table?

Here is my query:

```
 Repo.all(from p in Subjectclass, where: p.user_id == ^user.id,
                                          join: f in Subject,
                                          on: p.subject_id == f.id,
                                          join: z in Schedule,
                                          on: f.id == z.subject_id,
                                          where: z.weekday == 1,
                                          join: t in User,
                                          on: f.user_id == t.id,
                                          join: h in Homework,
                                          on: f.id == h.subject_id,
                                          where: h.deadline == ^this_monday,
                                          group_by: f.title,
                                          group_by: t.surname,
                                          group_by: z.timeslot_id,
                                          group_by: h.body,
                                          order_by: z.timeslot_id,
                                          select: %{title: f.title, teacher: t.surname, homework: h.body})
```

What happens is `where: h.deadline == ^this_monday,` checks whether there are any homeworks for that day for subjects. But if there is none (subject with no homework) it just removes that entire element from final result.

My question: is it possible to still include that element with no homework (i.e. title: "Math", teacher: "Bob", homework: "") in the final result (select:), or somehow substitute for space? In the current code, it just removes entire element from final result.

Thank you in advance!

Schemas:

```
schema "subjectclasses" do
  belongs_to :user, Kz.User
  belongs_to :subject, Kz.Subject
  timestamps()
end

schema "subjects" do
  field :lvl, :integer
  field :title, :string
  field :week, :integer
  belongs_to :user, Kz.User
  has_many :subjectclasses, Kz.Subjectclass
  timestamps()
end

schema "schedules" do
  field :subject_id, :integer
  field :weekday, :integer
  belongs_to :timeslot, Kz.Timeslot  
  timestamps()
end

schema "users" do
  field :firstname, :string
  field :surname, :string
  field :level, :integer
  field :username, :string
  field :encrypted_password, :string
  belongs_to :role, Kz.Role
  has_many :subjects, Kz.Subject
  has_many :subjectclasses, Kz.Subjectclass
  field :password, :string, virtual: true
  timestamps()
end

schema "homeworks" do
  field :body, :string
  field :deadline, Ecto.Date
  belongs_to :subject, Kz.Subject
  timestamps()
end
```

Comment: I think you want `left_join: h in Homework` (instead of `join`). That should give you `homework: nil` but I can't test without more details about the schema.

Comment: Hey @Dogbert, I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't help. So I add schema

Comment: Ah right. Ignore my comment; `left join` won't do anything here since the condition is in a `where`.

Comment: I've tried without the where: condition and it worked, however I still need it. I think where: removes elements that don't match condition AND elements with NULL values, as they are not in the Homework table at all.

Comment: @Dogbert I've made it work with left_join and slightly changed condition. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
left_join: h in Homework,
on: f.id == h.subject_id and h.deadline == ^this_monday,
```

so that the join is on unique fields in the Homework table.